# What does the second percentage number mean in caniuse.com stats?

Tags: caniuse

I want to know how many % of users can use `fit-content` so I searched it and found this [page](https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content).

However, what does the second number mean?

[image]

Comment: If you hover over that percentage you'll see that it's the percent of usages that are in a browser that only *partially support* the feature vs. the first percentage that is usage by browsers that totally support the feature.

Comment: thanks, first time I tried it's not showing up the tooltip box.